# How to pop up figure

Tags: r

I am using R-studio, I want to get pop-up window (for figure plotted) after each simulation. I was able to create and save the figure with following code.

I was just wondering if i can pop-up the figure.

```
 tiff("Calibration.tiff", width = 4, height = 2.5, units = 'in', res = 500)
 x=rnorm(30, 1, 2)
 y=rnorm(30,2,4)
 plot(x,y)
 dev.off()
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. You have all the figures stored in the "plot" pane, without writing files on disk. Please clarify what you are looking for.

Comment: I have plot statement between those two line.. i was able to plot it and save it. I am looking for a way by which i can pop-up these figure once it is   plotted (instead of going to folder and opening it)

Comment: It will depends on your OS then. Might be easy in *nix or OSX. Probably painful on Windows.

Comment: Do you mean you just want the plot to be visible? By using `tiff` you are redirecting the plot output to the file, which ends with `dev.off()`. You can re-plot the figure after (or before) that and have it also appear in your plot pane.

Comment: @JonathanCarroll  OP wants R to open the file written, using some `system` command.

Answer (score 2):

Adapted from [RStudio's documentation](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/202133558-Extending-RStudio-with-the-Viewer-Pane);

```
viewer <- getOption("viewer") 
viewer("Calibration.tiff")
```

launches an external program with the graphic loaded.

Alternatively,

```
shell.exec("C:\\UserData\\Documents\\Calibration.tiff")
```

will also launch whichever external viewer Windows has associated with that filetype. The name needs to be fully qualified or relative to the current directory.

Comment: Well, OP starts out with "I am using R-studio" so it's probably okay.